# C# Click HTML button on multiple webbrowsers

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, watin

So I have about 30 webbrowsers that I have to goto, then fill in a textbox, then click the button. The button doesnt have an ID so I cant do the GetElementById method. I tried WatiN but I lack the knowledge to do it on all browsers. Heres some source of my program.

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            webBrowser31.Document.GetElementById("inputSession").SetAttribute("value", textBox4.Text);
            webBrowser31.Button(Find.ByName("                  Enter              ")).Click();
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this for automated testing. Can you not just add an id to the button element?

Comment: Could you post some of the html code from the browser

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to find elements on a web page, even when there is absolutely no identifier you can get a hold of the different elements, you just have to find what's unique about them. For example, if you have five buttons on a web page and each button doesn't have absolutely anything to identify them you can always end up getting a collection of ALL buttons on that web page, like this:

`var allButtons = browser.Buttons;`

In that way even if there's absolutely no unique identifier for a button you will be able to identify the button by position or by the text on the button (if that helps in any way). The same goes for TextBoxes or any other element on a web page.

It is kind of confusing to me when you write  "I have about 30 webbrowsers" and "....to do it on all browsers" I hope you meant that you have 30 websites and that you want to do it on all websites